# File Icon Like JPanel

Tags: java, swing, file, icons, jpanel

[image]

Hi I want to create an JPanel which is very similar to the File Icon in Windows. It should have

- a image on the top,
- small indicator left bottom if it is a shortcut or some properties and file
- filename in the bottom. It should display only 10 characters by default after we selected it should display all the characters.
- right click on it should show some menu.
- This file icon panel should be fit into the given size (100 x 100 or 70 x 70)

Please show me some light how to make it.

Comment: create a custom component that extends `JPanel`

Comment: For the icon you might start with the code for [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).  Note that the native PLAF returns a much better icon than the Metal PLAF.  *"right click on it should show some menu."*  Look to the `Desktop` API to implement at least some of the right click functionality.

Comment: You need to show an attempt or have a real question. This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: i'm not sure that [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) would help you there!!

Comment: can you explain more JPanel is for adding component in JFrame to give better organization

Comment: I can put some code i tried, But its not really good looking. its common requirement, so if someone already tried it, they can help me.